# Function Optional Parameter in VBA Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following function which, in an Excel cell, is written as **`=FACING_CHANGE(live, optimal, [override])`**:

```
    Function FACING_CHANGE(live As Integer, opt As Integer, _
      Optional override As Range) As String

        If override.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(override.Value) = True Then
            opt = override.Value
        End If
        If live = opt Then
            FACING_CHANGE = "SAME " & live
        ElseIf live > opt And opt = 0 Then
            FACING_CHANGE = "DELETED"
        ElseIf live > opt And opt > 0 Then
            FACING_CHANGE = "DECREASED"
        ElseIf live < opt And live = 0 Then
            FACING_CHANGE = "ADDED"
        ElseIf live < opt And live > 0 Then
            FACING_CHANGE = "INCREASED"
        End If
    End Function
```

Which returns a string result. I'm having trouble with the optional `override` parameter. It's of type `range` right now because a blank cell returns a `0` if `override` were an `integer`, which is valid. I need it as an optional param because in ***most*** but not all cases it will be used with the 3rd parameter.

When I insert a breakpoint and step through, the function exits automatically at the first if statement (`If override.Value...`). Below are some results. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know if I'm having trouble! Thanks for the link!

Comment: Would adding a default value for the optional parameter help your case?

Answer (score 6):

When your `Range` optional parameter isn't specified, your function receives it as `Nothing`.

Then when this line runs:

```
If override.Value <> ""
```

I bet VBA is blowing up with an "object reference not set" error, because you're accessing a property on an object reference that's `Nothing`.

Solution is to simply check whether `override Is Nothing` before accessing it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to verify if the override range object is defined or not.
Try this:

```
Function FACING_CHANGE(live As Integer, opt As Integer, Optional override As Range) As String

    If Not override Is Nothing Then
        If override.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(override.Value) = True Then
            opt = override.Value
        End If
    End If
    If live = opt Then
        FACING_CHANGE = "SAME " & live
    ElseIf live > opt And opt = 0 Then
        FACING_CHANGE = "DELETED"
    ElseIf live > opt And opt > 0 Then
        FACING_CHANGE = "DECREASED"
    ElseIf live < opt And live = 0 Then
        FACING_CHANGE = "ADDED"
    ElseIf live < opt And live > 0 Then
        FACING_CHANGE = "INCREASED"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The link posted in the comments under the original question by @vba4all.com was really helpful. Here's the revised first if statement:

```
    If IsMissing(override) = False And VarType(override) = vbInteger Then
        If IsNumeric(override) = True Then opt = override
    End If
```

Also change Optional params to Variant if using IsMissing()

Comment: Note that this will still blow up if the function is passed `Nothing` - in which case the parameter will not be missing, but will not hold a valid `Range` reference either.

Comment: Note: `IsMissing` only works for `Variant` types, not simple types or `Object` (`Range` in this case). See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251721%28v=office.15%29.aspx